# How to get 8 direction Movement with controller sticks | Topdown 3D Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on an 3d rpg top down view in Unity. Something like the zelda links awakening remake.

What im trying to achieve ist that the player rotates to the direction you press and then just goes forwards and this in only 8 directions.

I already got this working with WASD and the dpad, there it obviously works because you cant press in between two buttons if you know what i mean.

But i need a way to clamp the joystick input to only the 8 directions. How can i achieve this ? I hope you understand what i mean. This is the code ive already written. Note that im using the new input system.

````
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private PlayerInputActions playerInput;
 
     private Rigidbody rb;
 
     [SerializeField]
     private float playerSpeed;
 
     private float angle;
 
     private Quaternion targetRotation;
 
     private Vector2 input;
 
     private Transform cam;
 
     void Awake()
     {
         playerInput = new PlayerInputActions();
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     }
 
     void Start()
     {
         cam = Camera.main.transform;
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         GetInput();
 
         if (input.x == 0 && input.y == 0) return;
 
         CalculateDirection();
         Rotate();
         Move();
     }
 
     void GetInput()
     {
         input.x = playerInput.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>().x;
         input.y = playerInput.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>().y;
     }
 
     void CalculateDirection()
     {
         if (input.sqrMagnitude > 1.0f)
             input = input.normalized;
 
         angle = Mathf.Atan2(input.x, input.y);
         angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * angle;
         angle += cam.eulerAngles.y;
     }
 
     void Rotate()
     {
         targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
         transform.rotation = targetRotation;
     }
 
     void Move()
     {
         //transform.position += transform.forward * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
         rb.velocity = transform.forward * 200 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
     }
 
     void OnEnable()
     {
         playerInput.Enable();
     }
 
     void OnDisable()
     {
         playerInput.Disable();
     }
 } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to keep results in the same way that you're working at moment

```
private void CalculateDirection (InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    var input = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    var x = Mathf.Abs(input.x) <= .1f ? 0f : // Deadzone
        input.x > 0 ? 1f : -1f; // Direction
    
    var y = Mathf.Abs(input.y) <= .1f ? 0f : 
        input.y > 0 ? 1f : -1f;
    
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(x, y);
    angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * angle;
 }
```

As you are working with gamepad stick and values here can be a range between -1..1 and when you get interactions from your keyboard buttons values are coming in 0, 1, or -1, similar to the `Input.GetAxisRaw()` in older input system, we don't need to normalize it.
This approach should work but I have a feeling that this will give some weird behaviors when controlling with the stick, I mean, maybe if you try to go up the player ends going to some side (UpRight or UpLeft) because the range for upper, down, right and left aren't really wide, I hope to be wrong but if I'm right you'll probably need to bite the bullet and manually decide a range/angle for each of the 8 sides. Try the above code and if you need help manually creating it just come back here and we try again.

N